# Функция не сохраняет переменные

Tags: python

Форумчане!
Возникла проблема с тем, что почему-то функция не хочет отдавать мне значение вычисленной переменной. Пишет, мол "Ошибка в 18 строке. Имя 'р' не найдено"... Объясните, как решить эту проблему (Это особенность функции или ошибка в коде? Желательно с более правильным вариантом). Заранее, спасибо!

```
def fr(p1, q1):

    p = p1
    q = q1

    while (p != 0) and (q != 0):
        if p > q:
            p = p % q
        else:
            q = q % p
        p = p + q
        return p

a = int(input('...'))
b = int(input('...'))

fr(a, b)

a = a // p
b = b // p
```

Answer (score 4):

Ошибка заключается в неверном понимании области видимости. Покажу более наглядно:

```
def fr(p1, q1):
    p = p1
    q = q1
    # тут есть переменная p
    while (p != 0) and (q != 0):
        if p > q:
            p = p % q
        else:
            q = q % p
        p = p + q
        # и вот тут есть переменная p
        return p
        # и даже тут переменная p ещё есть

# а вот тут её уже нет, поскольку тело функции закончилось
a = int(input('...'))
b = int(input('...'))

fr(a, b) # функция создала переменную p ВНУТРИ СЕБЯ, но снаружи никакой p нет!

# переменную p всё ещё не создали!
a = a // p
b = b // p
```

Как это должно работать:

```
def fr(p1, q1):
    p = p1
    q = q1

    while (p != 0) and (q != 0):
        if p > q:
            p = p % q
        else:
            q = q % p
        p = p + q
        return p

a = int(input('...'))
b = int(input('...'))

p = fr(a, b) # вот тут мы создаём эту переменную p и получаем в неё значение p из функции

# теперь p есть :) её можно использовать
a = a // p
b = b // p
```

---

Ну и, как указал автор другого ответа, у вас явно проблема с отступом около `return`, поскольку такой отступ полностью лишает смысла существование цикла - на первой же итерации функция закончится.
Впрочем, это уже ошибка логическая, и с вашим исключением она не связана.

---

Ах да, благодаря всё тому же понятию области видимости вы можете называть формальные параметры сразу нужными именами, а не присваивать их позже:

```
def fr(p, q):
    while (p != 0) and (q != 0):
        if p > q:
            p = p % q
        else:
            q = q % p
        p = p + q
    return p
```

Answer (score 2):

```
p = fr(a, b)
```

Ещё, скорее всего, у вас тут неправильный отступ:

```
def fr(p1, q1):

    p = p1
    q = q1

    while (p != 0) and (q != 0):
        if p > q:
            p = p % q
        else:
            q = q % p
        p = p + q
    return p
```